# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки выводился не новый холст с текстом, а чтобы текст заменял предыдущий?

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]         [появляется новый холст с новым скролом](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG6EK.png)

```
canvas_text = tk.Canvas(f3_text, width=500)
scroll_canv = tk.Scrollbar(f3_text, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
scroll_canv.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
scroll_canv.config(command=canvas_text.yview)
canvas_text.config(yscrollcommand=scroll_canv.set)
canvas_text.pack()
canvas_text.delete('all')
canvas_text.create_text(300, 600,
                        text=qq, width=200)

canvas_text.update_idletasks()
canvas_text.configure(scrollregion=canvas_text.bbox("all"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаете кнопку, прописываете функцию для неё - внутри функции очищаете канвас и создаете новый текст. Затем связываете функцию и кнопку.

```
import tkinter as tk


def change_text():  # функция для кнопки
    canvas_text.delete('all')  # очищаем канвас
    canvas_text.create_text(300, 600, text='текст после клика', width=200, anchor='nw') # создаем новый текст


f3_text = tk.Tk()
qq = 'текст до клика'
canvas_text = tk.Canvas(f3_text, width=500)
scroll_canv = tk.Scrollbar(f3_text, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
scroll_canv.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
scroll_canv.config(command=canvas_text.yview)
canvas_text.config(yscrollcommand=scroll_canv.set)
canvas_text.pack(padx=100)
canvas_text.create_text(300, 600, text=qq, width=200, anchor='nw')
canvas_text.update_idletasks()
canvas_text.configure(scrollregion=canvas_text.bbox("all"))
button = tk.Button(command=change_text, text='сменить текст')  # создаём кнопку
button.pack()  # размещаем кнопку в окне
f3_text.mainloop()
```

Вариант с учетом комментариев автора вопроса:

```
import tkinter as tk


def get_text():
    new_text = entry1.get()
    return new_text


def change_text():  # функция для кнопки
    qq = get_text()
    canvas_text.delete('all')  # очищаем канвас
    canvas_text.create_text(300, 600, text=qq, width=200,
                            anchor='nw')  # создаем новый текст


f3_text = tk.Tk()
qq = 'текст до клика'
entry1 = tk.Entry()
entry1.pack()
canvas_text = tk.Canvas(f3_text, width=500)
scroll_canv = tk.Scrollbar(f3_text, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
scroll_canv.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
scroll_canv.config(command=canvas_text.yview)
canvas_text.config(yscrollcommand=scroll_canv.set)
canvas_text.pack(padx=100)
canvas_text.create_text(300, 600, text=qq, width=200, anchor='nw')
canvas_text.update_idletasks()
canvas_text.configure(scrollregion=canvas_text.bbox("all"))
button = tk.Button(command=change_text, text='сменить текст')  # создаём кнопку
button.pack()  # размещаем кнопку в окне
f3_text.mainloop()
```

Comment: У меня от такой кнопки запускается главная программа которая ищет слова. т.е. пользователь вводит слово и нажимает кнопку,программа начинает работать и искать слово по его вводу. в переменной qq  не будет данных без его ввода и программа не заработает. Пробовал очищать канвас до первого создания текста, но тогда вообще не чего не выводится

Comment: Это часть кода для  канваса и для скрола, по тому что не смог прикрутить скрол к лейблу, а скрол нужен по тому что список слов может выйти очень большим

Comment: т.е. у вас при запуске программы на канвасе не должно быть текста? К лейблу не получится привязать скроллбар, tkinter это не предусматривает. Вы можете использовать Entry(однострочное поле) или Text(многострочное), к нему привязать скроллбар и в нём выводить нужный текст.

Comment: там может быть более 200 слов в однострочном поле будет не удобно. Текст в переменной qq образуется после нажатия кнопки, выводимые слова-зависят от введенного слова. Нажатие кнопки запускает основную программу, в конечном действии которой происходит добавление слов в канвас.

Comment: Но если ввести другое слово, и нажать кнопку создается новый холст, ниже предыдущего а не перезаписывается на нем, и так с каждым нажатием, даже если нажать без слово,создастся пустой холст . Это отображается как месиво из окон (канвасов) с их скроллами

Comment: прикрепил фото отобажения после трех нажатий на кнопки

Comment: Я вас понял. Такое может происходить, если у вас в функции, которая привязана к кнопке, вы создаете канвас, т.е. в функции присуствует код:
```canvas_text = tk.Canvas(f3_text, width=500)
canvas_text.pack()```
В моем ответе в функции кнопки ```def change_text():``` такой код отсутствует, т.е. новый канвас создаваться не должен. Я добавил в свой ответ ещё один вариант, в котором прописал текстовое поле, чтобы вы могли протестировать, работает ли этот код так, как вам надо. Вводите текст в это поле и жмите на кнопку - вы увидите, что меняется текст на канвасе, новых канвасов не создается.

Comment: А код основной программы для получения нового текста вы можете добавить в функцию ```def get_text():```

Comment: При запуске программа ломалась, т.к. значения определялись позже в ткинтере . Эту проблему решил при помощи кнопки. Т.е. пока пользователь не нажмет кнопку основной блок программ не будет работать.А если нажмет значения будут браться из ткинтера (даже если поля ввода пустые, значения будут браться) и программа заработает нормально(почти) Думаю сейчас сделать две кнопки одну для запуска программы, другую для получения результата. Думаю выглядеть это будет космато)))

Comment: тут нету личных сообщений?

Comment: возможно скинуть код целиком?

Comment: что то у меня встала каша колом со второй кнопкой , пока поучу мат часть, я бы хотел скинуть код целиком чтоб посмотрел кто-то опытный и подсказал.